# Batch: Word counter

Tags: powershell, batch, git, github

How to make a counter that counts a word "parent", from an external file, then divides it by 2 and after that "echo's" this to a document? This is a file  that will be downloaded, thats why it should be external. This is for version control on git.

I am making a usb flash drive system, and i want it to have an updater. I also want to use batch or powershell (i dont understand any powershell) as this is a standard tool that comes with windows.

Sorry my bad english today, i'm having a really bad day..

### EDIT

I have a better day today tho! Well, today i might be better to explain my problem!
I want to make a batch-script that counts the times that the word "parent" appaer in the file, http://api.github.com/repos/godzillamesel/disclovestory/commits:

I'm currenly downloading this file with:

--
cd "$env:programfiles\DiscLovestory\sys\update"
Remove-Item "git_commit.log"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
wget -O git_commit.log http://api.github.com/repos/godzillamesel/disclovestory/commits
pause

--

Having this is file is also gonna be needed as a "update-note" to the user.
This script went straight to powershell, since i don't know how bitsadmin works, but if you also know how that should work, be my guest to help me out! As my script is based to be a batch-only script.

I want the output to go to: "%programfiles%\DiscLovestory\sys\update\version.log" and also in registry:
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DiscLovestory /v DisplayVersion /t REG_SZ /d 
In both output places it should be enough to just put version as follow: "x.xx" without quotations.

And if you wanna follow up on the script, or use it, be my guest. It is open-source at:
https://github.com/godzillamesel/disclovestory

Comment: Bad days are never fun. :/ Regarding your question, I am not sure what exactly to make of "counts a word 'parent'". Given the rest of the question, do you you wish to take something similar to "ProgramName v1.0" and echo either "ProgramName" or "v1.0"?

Comment: Check the question again, i have a big edit over here. @Anaksunaman